# How to validate config values from appSettings.json file automatically during DI setup?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I added configurations to the appSettings.json file in my .NET Core project. For the sake of simplicy I'm taking database settings as an example. So in the settings file you would have

```
{
  "Database": {
    "Host": "localhost",
    "Port": 1234,
    "Database": "myDb",
    "Username": "username",
    "Password": "pw",
    "EnablePooling": true
  }
}
```

When configuring the services in the Startup.cs file I want to make those settings accessible via dependency injection. The data model for this is

```
public class DatabaseSettings
{
    public string Host { get; set; }
    public ushort Port { get; set; }
    public string Database { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public bool EnablePooling { get; set; }
}
```

and I configure it this way

```
private void SetupSettings(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ServiceProvider serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    IConfiguration configuration = serviceProvider.GetService<IConfiguration>();

    IConfigurationSection databaseConfigurationSection = configuration.GetSection("Database");
    services.Configure<DatabaseSettings>(databaseConfigurationSection);
}
```

Lastly I want to validate those settings. I know that I can create a validator class implementing the `IValidateOptions` interface.

```
public class DatabaseSettingsValidator : IValidateOptions<DatabaseSettings>
{
    private readonly IList<string> failures;

    public DatabaseSettingsValidator()
    {
        failures = new List<string>();
    }
    
    public ValidateOptionsResult Validate(string databaseSettingsName, DatabaseSettings databaseSettings)
    {
        if (databaseSettings == null)
            failures.Add($"{databaseSettingsName} are required.");
        
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(databaseSettings?.Host))
            failures.Add($"{nameof(databaseSettings.Host)} must not be empty.");
        
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(databaseSettings?.Database))
            failures.Add($"{nameof(databaseSettings.Database)} must not be empty.");
        
        if (failures.Any())
            return ValidateOptionsResult.Fail(failures);

        return ValidateOptionsResult.Success;
    }
}
```

but do I have to create this class and call the `Validate` method on my own? Maybe there is something like this sample code?

.

```
services.ValidateConfiguration<IOptions<DatabaseSettings>, DatabaseSettingsValidator>();
```

So you pass in the configured settings and the validator to use.

Answer (score 1):

> but I'm struggling with two questions:
>
> Is there a way I can collect all failures instead of returning after
> one? So you would get a list of failures instead of having to fix one
> by one.
>
> Do I have to create this class and call the Validate method on my own?
> Maybe there is something like this sample code?
>
> services.ValidateConfiguration<IOptions,
> DatabaseSettingsValidator>(); So you pass in the configured settings
> and the validator to use.

Yes, we could collect all failures list and display them at once, and we could also create a class which contains the Validate method. Please check the following steps:

First, since the class name is "**DatabaseSettings**", it better sets the config section name as the same as the class name:

```
{
  "DatabaseSettings": {
    "Host": "localhost",
    "Port": 1234,
    "Database": "myDb",
    "Username": "username",
    "Password": "pw",
    "EnablePooling": true
  }
}
```

[Note] If using a different name, the value might not map to the Database Setting class, so when validate the data, they all null.

Second, using the Data Annotations method adds validation rules to the model properties.

```
public class DatabaseSettings
{
    [Required]
    public string Host { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public ushort Port { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Database { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public bool EnablePooling { get; set; }
}
```

Third, create a ServiceCollectionExtensions class which contains the ConfigureAndValidate method:

```
public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection ConfigureAndValidate<T>(this IServiceCollection @this,
        IConfiguration config) where T : class
        => @this
            .Configure<T>(config.GetSection(typeof(T).Name))
            .PostConfigure<T>(settings =>
            {
                var configErrors = settings.ValidationErrors().ToArray();
                if (configErrors.Any())
                {
                    var aggrErrors = string.Join(",", configErrors);
                    var count = configErrors.Length;
                    var configType = typeof(T).Name;
                    throw new ApplicationException(
                        $"Found {count} configuration error(s) in {configType}: {aggrErrors}");
                }
            });
}
```

Then, register the ConfigureAndValidate service:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.ConfigureAndValidate<DatabaseSettings>(Configuration);
}
```

Finally, get the Exception list.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly DatabaseSettings_settings;

    public HomeController(IOptions<DatabaseSettings> settings)
    {
        _settings = settings.Value; // <-- FAIL HERE THROW EXCEPTION
    }
}
```

Then, test result like this (I removed the Host and Username from the appSettings.json):

[image]

More detail information, you can check this blog:[Validating configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://blog.bredvid.no/validating-configuration-in-asp-net-core-e9825bd15f10)

Comment: This looks like a real overkill, why should one implement the `IValidateOptions` interface then =?

Comment: I think this guy solved it with smaller effort https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57135724/how-to-validate-configuration-settings-using-ivalidateoptions-in-asp-net-core-2

Comment: but +1 for your solution :)

Answer (score 0):

ValidateOptions are mainly for complex scenario, the purpose of using ValidateOptions is that you can move the validate logic out of startup.

I think for your scenario, you can use below code as a reference

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddOptions<MyConfigOptions>()
        .Bind(Configuration.GetSection(MyConfigOptions.MyConfig))
        .ValidateDataAnnotations()
        .Validate(config =>
        {
            if (config.Key2 != 0)
            {
                return config.Key3 > config.Key2;
            }

            return true;
        }, "Key3 must be > than Key2.");   // Failure message.

    services.AddControllersWithViews();
}
```

For more details, please refer to this document
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-3.1#options-validation