# Validating appsettings that are loaded in with IConfiguration

Tags: c#, appsettings

I am working on a program that reads in its configuration from an `appsettings.json`.

The relevant section in the appsettings looks something like this:

```
"Sources":
  {
    "SourceList":
    [
      {
        "Name": "First Source",
        "RequestInfo": {
          "Url": "some Url",
          "Headers": {}
        },
        "Successors": null
      },
      {
        "Name": "Second Source",
        "RequestInfo": {
          "Url": [1, 2, 5],
          "Headers": {
            "Authorization": "SecretAccessToken123"
          }
        },
        "Successors": null
      },
    ]
  }
```

The section is read in and "mapped" to an instance of the class `SourceOptions` like this:

```
services.Configure<SourceOptions>(hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("Sources"));
```

Here is what `SourceOptions.cs` looks like:

```
public class SourceOptions
{
    public List<Source> SourceList { get; set; }
}

public class Source
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    public RequestInfo RequestInfo { get; set; }
    
    public List<Source>? Successors { get; set; }
}
```

All of this works just fine as long as everything in the appsettings is in correct format.
To ensure this, I have implemented a validator for the SourceOptions to make sure that bad input by the user is detected right at the start and doesn't lead to errors later in the program.

The problem now is that apparently, when one entry of one Source in the appsettings doesn't match the property of my Source class, the whole Source object will not be loaded.
For the example appsettings.json at the top of my question, the SourceList in SourceOptions will contain only one Source (First Source), because the second source contains this faulty data: `"Url": [1, 2, 5]`.

What would be a good way to validate the appsettings when subsections with faulty data are not loaded into my SourceOptions?
My SourceOptionsValidator can't throw an error because the only Source it receives is "First Source".

My only idea right now would be to *also* read in the appsettings as a JObject, then make a list of sources that it contains and compare that to the sources that end up in SourceOptions to check if some Source is missing.
But this way, I could only give feedback like *"Source "Second Source" contains some bad entry somewhere"* without a detailed description of the error.

Is there a better way?

Comment: you could write a validator for the SourceOptions like here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57135724/how-to-validate-configuration-settings-using-ivalidateoptions-in-asp-net-core-2

Comment: Tried it and I have the exact same problem: Sources that contain some bad input in the appsettings are simply not loaded into SourceOptions, so I can validate those all I want - the validator can't find an error in something he can't even look at